# MySQL Selecting from two tables ordered by date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

*Beginner here so please go easy on me :)*

So I have these two tables in my DB

#### Reply Table

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| message_id | client_id | message | date_posted |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

#### Request Table (Exactly the same)

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| message_id | client_id | message | date_posted |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

#### Problem:

They serve a messaging app I was testing but now I don't know how to query these tables to get all chat ordered by date from two tables. For example

> Client 14 (2 hours ago): Hello there // Coming from request table
>   Admin (1 hour ago): Welcome // Coming from reply table

So the messages are displayed oldest first...

I tried using `JOIN` on **`clien_id`** since that is what I want. However, it doesn't seem to work.

I also tried selecting from a subquery containing `UNION ALL`, also no luck... Any ideas on how this can be done? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you try Union All?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `union` is what you're looking for. In your case, a `join` would combine columns from the two tables into a single row, where as you're looking to `union` rows from multiple tables into a single result set.

You'll want to enclose your select statements individually, and then add the order clause.

**Edit: Updating this answer to include a column for the source table, as per OP's comment**

```
(select source='reply_table', * from reply_table)
union
(select source='request_table', * from request_table)
order by date_posted desc
```

MySQL's docs are pretty good, and its page on unions outlines several sorting scenarios: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

But the instruction specific to your case is:

> To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION result, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.. Worked.. I did have to add a flag column to the tables to know which message is coming from which table... THANKS A LOT!!!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it helped! My suggestion for "telling which table the message came from" would be to put the value right in your select query, rather than a whole new column. Eg: `select source='reply', * from reply_table`

Comment: damn.. I didn't know that was possible.. They don't teach you that hot stuff at Treehouse or University

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.message
from table1 a
inner join
table2 b 
on a.client_id=b.client_id 
order by a.date_posted desc;
```

Comment: message in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Use a.message or b.message

Comment: Not what I wanted

Comment: Thanks for trying though